# testing Intel SGX Remote Attestation

Tags: linux, sgx

Is it possible to use a server with Intel SGX to test Remote attestation? Is it possible to use my own local machine (which I use to connect to the SGX server) as cache service? how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before all, I suggest you read [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/code-sample/software-guard-extensions-remote-attestation-end-to-end-example.html), it contains almost everything you need to know about RA.

Then: in terms of RA, client and server might have interchangeable roles, so I will stick to this documentation that states: the server holds the secrets and attests a client's enclave.

In this setup, the server doesn't need to have an enclave, so yes, you can use any computer to run this part of the process.